# Signal R client javascript funtion not being called nor executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, aspnetboilerplate

I am currently developing a web application using asp.net MVC and asp.net boilerplate framework. Recently I just tried implementing real time updates using Signal R 2.2.1, But my callbacks on my JavaScript client are not been called nor executed. I don't know where I have gone wrong, please how do I get my client callback to be excited. Thanks, Below are my code.

My Signal R Hub

```
public class WallHub : Hub, ITransientDependency
{
     public async Task WallInit()
     {
         var wallItems = await ItemManager.GetAllItemsAsync();
         Clients.Caller.ItemListInitialized(wallItems);
     }
}
```

My JavaScript Code

```
$(function () {
    var wallHubProxy = $.connection.wallHub;
    wallHubProxy.client.itemListInitialized = function (itemLsts) {
    console.log(itemLsts);
  };

  $.connection.hub.start()
       .done(function () {
            wallHubProxy.server.wallInit();
       })
       .fail(function () {
            console.log("Could Not Connect");
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the client method from `WallHub`, you should call it keeping the capitalization - so you should call

`Clients.Caller.itemListInitialized(wallItems);`

Best of luck,

Radu M